# Embedding: mono vs lua

Tags: c++, mono, lua, embedding, mono-embedding

I am interested in hearing about peoples experience with embedding mono (open source implementation of .NET) in a C/C++ application. How is it to distribute such an application and what are the dependencies? I have tested on OS X and mono comes as a huge framework (hundreds of MB). Do users of my app all need this big framework or can it be stripped down or everything be compiled into the main executable.

I previously have experience with embedding Lua in a C++ app, and that works really well because I can link statically the whole lua interpreter in with my main executable. So I have no external dependencies. Is it possible to do something similar with mono?

Any Lua people here who can comment on how they found mono compared to Lua?

PS: By embedding I mean a C++ application which initializes a mono environment and loads a .NET assembly and executes it and then allows for communication between say C# code in assembly and C++ methods in main executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably also take a look at Mono's [Small Footprint](http://www.mono-project.com/Small_footprint) page that describes how you can embed a smaller runtime. Heck, they do it themselves with [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, is mscorlib.dll and the JIT the only things that are required to get mono embedded? Is there a way to statically link mscorlib.dll?

Comment: Mono allows you to completely statically link your code, so you probably don't even need the JIT. Have a look at their iPhone implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is 2 years old question. So situation may become different now.

For me, most important point was GC. I embedded Lua for interactive-apps and games, because incremental GC required. Currently Lua 5.1 has precise, incremental GC, but I couldn't found any proof of incremental or precise GC on Mono. So memory will leak (even it's very tiny!), and apps will struggle intermittently.

People says GC pause can be solved by tuning some parameters and pooling objects, but as I experienced, It *never* be solved without any kind of **distribution GC load over time** approach in GC. Generational GC is one of distribution algorithm, but it's too rough, and almost not helpful.

Because you can't control lifetime pattern or reuse instance by pooling the objects used in code that not yours. (such as basic class library)

So I don't recommend the C# platform (Mono or .NET, at least yet) for interactive/(soft)realtime apps.

---

Edit

I don't know whether any incremental/concurrent approached GC is presented on Mono or .NET. If you can sure about they offer the kind of GC, of course, it's fine to use :)

Comment: Even with over 2000 games built on Mono in the iOS App Store?

Comment: @Dave How about number of games in C/C++? :) The number doesn't proof presence of incremental GC. If you don't need serious interactivity, you can go for old GC. But if your users care about even very tiny time of pause, you'll regret.

Comment: I think this is pointless. If others can make a game in Mono, your requirement to have an 'incremental GC' are moot.

Comment: @Dave We can make game with anything! Just *possible to make*? is more pointless and moot. In old days, (and maybe still yet) there were text-only games made with ASM. Somebody makes a game with only sounds. If your games are these games, well.. we don't have to consider anything. But, if you're talking about *modern* games (have smooth animations and interactive graphics), yes that's what I'm saying. Well-made GC is *required* to this graphics. In my opinion, incremental GC is the biggest benefit of Lua vs Mono unless someone clarify Mono has nice GC.

Comment: I don't share your opinion on this. The typical effect of a "bad" GC would be a tiny hickup once every few minutes (from experience developing a 3D game heavily relying on Mono).

But as of Mono 3.0, there's now a concurrent GC.

Comment: @Cygon Well, about the hiccups, it's just problem about quality basis. You may fine with it, but your users may not. If you're making hard-core fighting action or music based game (a.k.a rhythm action) even a little tiny hiccups won't be forgiven because most users can feel difference of 1/60 second. Anyway, thanks for pointing about concurrent GC on Mono. Can I have the link about their GC? I want to know kind of GC they are using.

Comment: You'll find it in just about any release announcement about Mono 3.0. Here's a link to the blog of the developer describing it in detail: http://schani.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/sgen-concurrent-mark/ - In short, the "Mark" phase is now concurrent and the sweep phase is incremental similar to Lua.